# Es posible convertir un ArrayList<List<String>> to Array[] o a List<String[]>

Tags: java, array, arraylist, java-8, conversión-de-tipos

Tengo dos arraylist, este es el primero: `ArrayList<List<String>> Lista1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>`

y este es el segundo: `ArrayList<List<String>> Lista2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>`.

tengo que comparar estas dos listas, si su contenido es igual.
un ejemplo del contenido de Lista1 es: `[[AB,Seccion1,15,16,17],[AC,Seccion2,18,19,20],[AD,Seccion3,32,34,35]]`

un ejemplo del contenido de Lista2 es: `[[AB,Seccion1,20,26,27],[AF,Seccion4,38,39,30],[AD,Seccion3,42,44,45]]`

Basicamente comparar por ejemplo [AB,Seccion1,15,16,17] vs [AB,Seccion1,20,26,27] pero al ser datos de tipo  ArrayList<List> se complica más...
o ustedes saben como los puedo comparar? o convertir para que sea más sencillo...
o generar un método genérico para ello.

****Información general****

*El código "real" maneja muchos datos de entrada. Por ejemplo lista 1=82 y lista2=80

*El tamaño del arraylist no siempre es el mismo pero el tamaño de cada mm sub lista es el mismo. [AB,Seccion1,20,26,27].

*En general, se realiza un query en base a la fecha.
Lista1 es el resultado de la fecha1 y lista2 es el resultado de la fecha2.
Lo que se quiere es comparar las diferencias que hubo en esas fechas en cada una de las secciones.
Por eso es que lista1 y lista2 se puede encontrar la misma sección pero con diferentes valores, incluso a veces no vienen las misas secciones ya que tal vez ese día no estuvieron disponibles.

Comment: Añade el código que has intentado para que se te pueda ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunas cuestiones asumí convenientemente como:

- Los arreglos de las listas siempre tienen el mismo tamaño
- las listas también tienen el mismo tamaño
  Puedes compararlos de la siguiente manera

  ```
    ArrayList<List<String>> LA_1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    ArrayList<List<String>> LA_2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<String> L1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> L2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> L3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> L4 = new ArrayList<String>();

         L1.add("AB");
    L1.add("Seccion1");

    L2.add("AC");
    L2.add("Seccion2");

    L3.add("AB");
    L3.add("Seccion1");

    L4.add("AD");
    L4.add("Seccion4");

    LA_1.add(L1);
    LA_1.add(L2);

    LA_2.add(L3);
    LA_2.add(L4);


    int index = 0; // asumiendo que ambas listas son siempre del mismo tamaño
    for (List<String> tmpList_LA_1 : LA_1) {
        List<String> tmpList_LA_2 = LA_2.get(index);
        for (int i = 0; i < tmpList_LA_2.size(); i++) {
            String l1 = tmpList_LA_1.get(i);
            String l2 = tmpList_LA_2.get(i);
            int areSame = l1.compareTo(l2);
            System.out.println(l1+" - "+l2+" son iguales:" + areSame); // 0:true -1:false
        }

        index++;

    }
  ```

output

```
AB - AB,             son iguales:0
Seccion1 - Seccion1, son iguales:0
AC - AD,             son iguales:-1
Seccion2 - Seccion4, son iguales:-2
```